# How do I define a variable when I call CMake, so that qtcreator knows it is defined?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I have a section of code that is conditionally activated depending on a #define, like this:

```
#ifdef VARIABLE
  code.function();
#endif
```

The cmake script has an 'options' command that sets the VARIABLE like this:

```
option(VARIABLE "Want to use VARIABLE?" ON)

if(VARIABLE)
   message(STATUS "VARIABLE")
   set(VARIABLE_FLAG "-DVARIABLE")
endif()

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${VARIABLE_FLAG} -Wall")
```

I'm using cmake to build the project and qtcreator as IDE. My problem is that qtcreator thinks that VARIABLE is not defined so my code has is not highlighted, but when I build it on a console, VARIABLE is defined. So, what parameters should I pass to qtcreator to run cmake, so that it knows VARIABLE is defined and highlights my code? Is there a way to do this?

Ps: I just use qtcreator to edit files, the build part is done via console commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use a configured header file, and include it only where you need the definition:

```
# in CMakeLists.txt
configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_defs.h.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_defs.h
  )

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

and

```
// in my_defs.h.in
#cmakedefine VARIABLE
  // configure_file converts #cmakedefine of a named CMake variable
  // into a C++ #define of a C++ pre-processor symbol
```

and finally

```
// in various C++ source or header files, but only as needed:
#include "my_defs.h"
#ifdef VARIABLE
  doSome_VARIABLE_SpecificStuff();
#endif
```

I do not use QtCreator regularly, so I don't know if this technique works in terms of their syntax highlighting, but I'd assume it would, since they must read header files in order to do a proper job of it...

Comment: More complexity than I'd like just to fix qtcreator's syntax highlight, but it works. Besides, I've learned how to configure header files using cmake, so I think it was a great answer. Also, thanks for making my question clearer.

Comment: You're welcome! In general I think it's best to use a header file that's only included where necessary to do something like this. That way, only files that need to rebuild will be rebuilt on an incremental rebuild after changing the value of VARIABLE in CMake... The 2nd best way is to use add_definitions() at the top level CMakeLists file so that all compiled files get the definition. But then if you change the value in CMake, it leads to a full rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [add_definitions()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_definitions). It adds a preprocessor-define to the compiler and can be used like any ordinary `#define`:

```
add_definitions( -DVARIABLE )
```

However... I am not sure if this will make qtcreator pick it up as a 'known variable'.

Comment: I had already tried something similar, just not using add_definitions. Anyway, it didn't work. Looks like qtcreator ignores compiler definitions.

Comment: For what it's worth: on Qt Creator 4.1.0, using "add_definitions(-DVARIABLE)" as suggested by Andre does seem to have an effect on how Qt Creator displays preprocessor defines.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **project_name.config** file. It is specifically used for your need. You can add defines which are only interpreted by QtCreator for highlighting and auto-completion.

This file is normally in the root folder of your project.